# Should I use objects passed to Constructor during Injection?

Tags: c#, ioc-container

I understand one of the (maybe best) ways of using inversion of control is by injecting the dependent objects through the constructor (constructor injection).

However, if I make calls to these objects *outside* of the object using them, I feel like I am violating some sort of rule - is this the case? I don't think there is any way of preventing that from happening, but should I establish a rule that (outside of mocked objects) we should never call methods from these objects?

[EDIT] Here's a simplified example of what I am doing. I have a `FileController` object that basically is used for cataloging files. It uses a `FileDal` object that talks to the database to insert/query/update `File` and `Directory` tables.

On my real implementation I build the controller by instructing Castle to use a SQL Server version of the DAL, in my unit test I use an in-memory Sqlite version of the DAL. However, due to the way the DAL is implemented, I need to call BeginTransaction and Commit around the usage of the `FileController` so the connection does not get closed and I can later make retrievals and asserts. Why I have to do that is not much important, but it led me to think that calling methods on a DAL object that is used by other clients (controllers) didn't sound kosher. Here's an example:

```
FileDal fileDal = CastleFactory.CreateFileDal();
fileDal.BeginTransaction();
FileController fileController = new FileController(fileDal);
fileController.CallInterestingMethodThatUsesFileDal();
fileDal.Commit();
```

Comment: I'm very interested in seeing a simplified example of what you're actually doing. This can give us a bit more insight in your particular situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the type of object - but in general, I'd expect that to be okay.

Indeed, quite often the same dependency will be injected into many objects. For example, if you had an `IAuthenticator` and several classes needed to use authentication, it would make sense to create a single instance and inject it into each of the dependent classes, assuming they needed the same configuration.

I *typically* find that my dependencies are immutable types which are naturally thread-safe. That's not always the case, of course - and in some cases (with some IoC containers, at least) you may have dependencies automatically constructed to live for a particular thread or session - but "service-like" dependencies should generally be okay to call from multiple places and threads.

Comment: Thank you, Jon. In my case they are mostly DAL objects and you are indeed correct, they are created through Castle and then passed to various "controllers". I asked because I am writing unit tests and I had to initiate and terminate a transaction *outside* of the client object and that didn't feel right. Oh btw, I am *not* talking to a real database, I am running unit tests with in-memory Sqlite.